# yarn add dependency to worskpace from another workspace

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Say, I have a root package with two workspaces, `app` and `calc`.
In npm I use `npm install -w app calc` which makes the `app` package to depend on the `calc` package.
What is `yarn` equivalent of this command? I run `yarn workspace app add calc -W` and it adds the dependency to the global package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `yarn workspace app add calc --peer`. This will add **calc** package as a peer dependency to the **app** workspace.